# Question regarding the definition of intermediate field

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Say I have a field extension $L\supset K$.
My question is whether $L$ and $K$ themselves are considered intermediate fields, i.e. whether the inclusions in a tower $L\supset M\supset K$ have to be strict for $M$ to be considered an intermediate field.

Comment: Usually $K$ and $L$ themselves are intermediate fields of the field extension $L/K$.

Comment: Your question is rather a question on the notation $L\supset K$. Often this is denoted by $L\supseteq K$, from which it is obvious that equality counts also for the definition of an intermediate field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Dietrich Burde already mentioned in the comments, one usually defines an intermediate field $M$ of a field extension $L/K$ to be a field such that $K \subseteq M \subseteq L$. Though, some authors might use $\subset$ for $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ for $\subset$.